# If/else condition in Cypress not working as expected

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have this code

```
Cypress.Commands.add('VerifyLoginState', () => {
    if(cy.contains('Login')) {
        cy.get('.form-control').eq(0).type('firstfield')
        cy.get('.form-control').eq(1).type('secondfield')
        cy.get('.btn-login').click()
        cy.wait(2500)
        cy.contains('Upcoming Appointments').should('be.visible')
    }
    else
    {
        cy.contains('Appointment summary').should('be.visible')
    }
})
```

How should I write the code so that it can pass to the condition of else, when I am authenticated in the browser and the condition of if is not valid?

In other words, I want to check if an element is present on the page, and even if it is not present, the code should not give an error and move on

Answer (score 1):

Cypress *yields* the result of `cy` functions, and does not return them. So your if/else will not work as it would in traditional JavaScript. [Check out this article from Cypress about conditional testing.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence)
Something like the following should help you out:

```js
// Get the body of the DOM
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  // Check if the body contains the `Login` element
  if ($body.contains('Login').length) {
        cy.get('.form-control').eq(0).type('firstfield')
        cy.get('.form-control').eq(1).type('secondfield')
        cy.get('.btn-login').click()
        cy.wait(2500)
        cy.contains('Upcoming Appointments').should('be.visible')
    } else {
        cy.contains('Appointment summary').should('be.visible')
    }
```

Comment: That `$body.contains('Login').length` looks incorrect - the jQuery docs shows `contains` syntax is `$.contains(element, $body)` and the Cypress docs show `$body.find('Login').length` (on the page you linked to).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use within

ref: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within#Syntax

```
cy.contains('Login')
    .within(() => {
        cy.get('.form-control').eq(0).type('firstfield')
        cy.get('.form-control').eq(1).type('secondfield')
        cy.get('.btn-login').click()
        cy.wait(2500)
        cy.contains('Upcoming Appointments').should('be.visible')
      })
```

Comment: I don't think your solution solves their issue, as it doesn't contain the `else` portion.

Comment: yes it doesn't ,  it is another approach

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to test for either/or text using jQuery `:contains` and multiple selectors separated by a comma

```js
cy.get('body')
  .children(':contains(Login), :contains(Appointment summary)')  // only one is on the page
  .invoke('text')
  .then(labelText => {
    if (labelText.trim() === 'Login') {
      cy.get('.form-control').eq(0).type('firstfield')
      ... etc
    } else {
      cy.contains('Appointment summary').should('be.visible')
    }
  })
```